# Magento 2.3.1 : Add addition column in sales_order table using db_schema

Tags: magento2, magento2.3.1, declarative-schema, datatable

How to add addition column in sales_order table using db_schema or in Magento2.3.1 best way?

Comment: use db_schema which is the easiest way to add columns or to delete column no need of script upgrade..

Comment: but whole sales_order table need to define again in my script?

Comment: Check Ref: http://www.codextblog.com/magento-2/how-to-add-a-custom-column-in-order-grid-in-magento-2/

Comment: @RakeshDonga First try to understand my requirement. I am not asking for grid

Comment: @RutveeSojitra is it working for you?

Answer (score 3):

Create a new module depending on Magento_Sales and create a db_schema.xml file to declare the to be created a column in it. Once it is declared, generate the db_schema_whitelist.json file and run setup:upgrade. (db_schema.xml file is introduced in magento2.3 to run DB command to create, update tables and columns and keys. There is no need not for setup install scripts for a table but yes to populate columns you still need to use the old methodology of setup upgradeSchema)

**etc/module.xml**

```
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Module/etc/module.xsd">
<module name="FirstVendor_FirstModule"  setup_version="1.1.12" />
 <sequence>
        <module name="Magento_Sales"/>
 </sequence>
```

**registration.php**

```
use \Magento\Framework\Component\ComponentRegistrar;

ComponentRegistrar::register(ComponentRegistrar::MODULE, 'FirstVendor_FirstModule', __DIR__);
```

**etc/db_schema.xml**

```
<schema xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
        xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Setup/Declaration/Schema/etc/schema.xsd">
    <table name="sales_order" resource="default" engine="innodb">
        <column xsi:type="varchar" name="custom_column" length="100" unsigned="false" nullable="false" identity="false"
                 comment="Custom Name"/>
    </table>
</schema>
```

Finally, run this below command to generate whitelist (Even though it's not mandatory. Without this, it will create column too but as a standard approach recommended.)

```
php bin/magento setup:db-declaration:generate-whitelist
```

Once above command is executed, run the setup:upgrade to make it in effect.

```
php bin/magento setup:upgrade
```

Let me know if this helps.

Comment: Perform the same above steps for change quote column customer_note column type from varchar to text. But I got ```Invalid Document Element 'column', attribute 'length': The attribute 'length' is not allowed.``` error while run setup:upgrade command. This error comes because of in magento quote module db_schema.xml file has this customer_note definition and it's type varchar and has a length. If remove length from that definition line then code working without any error

Answer (score 1):

Try to use this below code :

> app/code/RH/SalesCustom/etc/module.xml

```
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Module/etc/module.xsd">
    <module name="RH_SalesCustom" >
        <sequence>
            <module name="Magento_Sales"/>
        </sequence>
    </module>
</config>
```

> app/code/RH/SalesCustom/registration.php

```
<?php

use Magento\Framework\Component\ComponentRegistrar;

ComponentRegistrar::register(
    ComponentRegistrar::MODULE,
    'RH_SalesCustom',
    __DIR__
);
```

> app/code/RH/SalesCustom/etc/db_schema.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<schema xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
        xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Setup/Declaration/Schema/etc/schema.xsd">
    <table name="sales_order">
        <column xsi:type="int" name="custom_sales_id" padding="10" unsigned="true" nullable="false"
                comment="Custom Sales ID"/>
        <constraint xsi:type="foreign" referenceId="SALES_ORDER_REFERRED_BY_SALES_ORDER_ENTITY_ID" table="sales_order"
                    column="custom_sales_id" referenceTable="sales_order" referenceColumn="entity_id" onDelete="CASCADE"/>
    </table>
</schema>
```

- custom_sales_id : your custom column name

Then run following command to generate **db_schema_whitelist.json**

> php bin/magento setup:db-declaration:generate-whitelist

Then, upgrade command execute :

> php bin/magento s:up

Comment: What's the use of padding?

Comment: It's size of int field.

Comment: then what about length? Isn't it the same with length as well?

Comment: Please read this : https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.4/extension-dev-guide/declarative-schema/db-schema.html